# JQuery Form Submit inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, zip

```
function GenerateZipPackage() {
    var drpListSelected = $("#drpCourse").chosen().val(); --I am using a chosen multiselect library 

    $.each(drpListSelected, function(i, courseId) {
        $('#CurrentCourseId').val(courseId);
        $("#frmZipPackages").submit();
    });
}
```

Depending on the courseId I am generating the zip course package for download.
        But when I run this code I only get one zip package for the last CourseId in the drpListSelected. Going through the JS documentation I think the .each loop is a synchronous call hence all the other form submit calls are not getting called. I tried to look round a bit and found another way to solve this i.e  Send the whole list to the server side code and return a Single zip file of multiple zip files for each course. But the individual file size is around 2mb and I am sure I will run into  memory exceptions if lot of courseIds are selected. Can anyone help me in the right direction? If I can submit the form in sequential queue I think I will be done with this without changing anything on the server side (As we already have the code to create single package at a time on form submit)

Comment: please show your entire form. If you are trying to send only id's maybe ajax would be more helpful? Also you can try to debug your code by adding `drpListSelected` to `console.log` to ensure that you are iterating over correct values

Comment: @dganenco I cannot add the whole form, its a very big code base. The basic form structure looks like this          using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ZipIntegration", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmZipPackages", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))  ..I have debugged through the code. I can see the selected values correctly but even after running the form submit I am not hitting the debugger until I reach the last iteration in the loop. Only on after the last iteration of the for loop is called I can see the debugger on the server side getting activated. Only one form submit is called.

Comment: If form is being submitted using browser default process it can only be submitted once.

Comment: Correct and good catch from @charlietfl You should use ajax call instead, if u want to submit each id separately. I will provide an example

Comment: When you `.submit()` your form, that's it. The browser is sending off the form values to the server and loading up something new. You have to make the calls in the background, via `Ajax`. And of course you also have to catch the responses coming back from `Ajax` and do something with them

Answer (score 0):

Example with ajax calls insted of form submission

```
 function GenerateZipPackage() {
        var drpListSelected = $("#drpCourse").chosen().val();  // we assume  drpListSelected = ['01', '23'];
      var $currentCurseId = $('#CurrentCourseId'); //defined once, used multiple times

      drpListSelected.forEach(function(courseId) {
        $currentCurseId.val(courseId);
        sendAjax(courseId);
      });
    }

    function sendAjax(courseId) {
      $.ajax('your url', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {courseId:courseId},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp) {
          console.log(resp);
        },
        error: function(req, status, err) {
          console.error('something went wrong', status, err);
        }
      });
    }
```